# code behaviour is strange

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, coding-style

I just switched to C++ from C# 
I wrote a link list code in C++ ran it in win32 console application and getting very strange errors while build

I pointed out 3 errors in comments , rest I cant type ,its too much .

```
using namespace std;

class float_list
{
     struct node
    {
        double data;
        struct node *next;
     };
        node *head;
public:

    float_list(void)
    {
        head = nullptr;
    };

    void appendNode(double);

};
//void float_list::appendNode(float num)
//{
//      
//}
void float_list::appendNode(double num)
    {
        node *newNode; 
        node *ptr; //here i am getting this Error error C3872:
                       //'0xa0': this character is not allowed in an identifier  , 
                       // how ever I changed its name again and again.  

        newNode = new node;
        newNode->data = num; // here un declared identifier ,
                         //also missing ; before this line 
        newNode->next = nullptr;


    if (!head)
    {       
        head = newNode;
    }
    else 
    {       
                ptr = head;     

                while (ptr->next)
                {
                ptr = ptr->next;
                ptr->next = newNode;
                };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you copy-paste it from an HTML page? IIRC, 0xa0 is nbsp.

Comment: Have you copy-pasted any code that was saved in Unicode format? '0xa0' is a non-breaking space and may not be recognized by your compiler.

Comment: there's an error in your last `while` loop: `ptr->next = newNode;` should be *outside* the loop. Also, it's better to maintain both *head* and *last* node pointers for a list; that way you won't need to traverse the whole list again and again on each new `appendNode`.

Comment: @WillNess please explain the line of code you talking about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem probably isn't the identifier, but the white space
around it.  `0xA0` is the Latin-1 code for a non-breaking
space.  It's not a legal character in input, and for some reason, the
compiler is treating it as part of the identifier.  If nothing else works, delete the line and reenter it, making sure that all spaces are normal spaces.  (I'm not sure under Windows, but I think a control-space or a shift-space will enter the nonbreaking space.)

Answer (score 5):

Others helped you with the invalid character that got pasted into your code somehow; but BTW, I think there's an error in your last `while` loop: `ptr->next = newNode;` should be outside the loop:

```
void float_list::appendNode(double num)
{
  // ... 
  if (!head)
  {     
    head = newNode;
  }
  else 
  {     
    ptr = head;     
    while (ptr->next)
    {
      ptr = ptr->next;
      // ptr->next = newNode;
    };
    ptr->next = newNode;  // here - at the end of the list
  }
}
```

Also, it's better to maintain both head and last node pointers for a list; that way you won't need to traverse the whole list again and again on each new call to `appendNode`.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the question, which is about compilation errors, not functional deficiencies.

Comment: @RobKennedy the OP asked me to explain this my remark in the comments to his question. So I did. Others helped him already with the invalid character that got pasted in somehow.

Answer (score 4):

The error complaining about the `0xa0` character, and the following semi-colon error are, I believe, both caused by a character that got accidentally copied into your code, which is a unicode character that you can't see, but just because you can't see it doesn't mean it's not there and wreaking havoc!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the 0xA0 non breaking space character.  I resolved it by highlighting a single character, copying it using ^C, then doing a Find and Replace All with a normal space.  You'll need to paste the non breaking space into the Find field using ^V.