# Strings in a preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, syntax-error, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to create a preprocessor define to simplify the following function

```
std::string LogError(LogManager::Severity severity, std::string message, int destinationMask = LOGFILE, std::string filename="");
```

Using the following `#define`

```
#define LogManagerErr(x) LogManager::getSingletonPtr()->LogError(LogManager::LC_ERR, x)
```

However when I try to use it like so

```
LogManagerErr("Error");
```

I get the following error:

> error C3872: '0xa0': this character is not allowed in an identifier

I've tried using the # in the define, but had no improvement.. can this be done?

Comment: You don't need a macro to do this. A regular function works fine.

Comment: @Avengre What compiler are you using? Compiles fine on VS 2015 and on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4129ff6beebaf96f) too.

Comment: 0xa0 might be a non-breaking space in your source code (which won't work well).

Comment: you could use a template instead of macros

Comment: I believe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436134/code-behaviour-is-strange